# VSTO Ribbon Combo Box Add items Dynamically

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, add-in, outlook-addin

How to add the Combo Box items dynamically ?

I have a Combo Box, where i will call the API during the OnChange Call Back event. Have a problem in loading the items to combo box

```
    public void OnChange(Office.IRibbonControl control, string text)
    {            
        var result = GETMembersList("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all");

        var members = from member in result
                      select member;

        foreach (var member in members)
        {
            dsMember mem = new dsMember();
            mem.Id = member["numericCode"].ToString();
            mem.Name = member["name"].ToString();

            RibbonDropDownItem item = Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory().CreateRibbonDropDownItem();
            item.Label = mem.Name;
            **cmbMembers.Items.Add(item);** ?? //problem here, cant access the combo box
        }
```

Ribbon.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="tabTest" label="TEST">
        <group id="grpTest">
          <comboBox id="cmbMembers" label="Users" showImage="false" 
                  onChange="OnChange"/>
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Comment: Have you tried `Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.cmbMembers.Items.Add(item);`?

Comment: @haindl ya i tried, but Ribbon1 is null.

Comment: From the Office point of view there is no way to create Ribbons without the XML. Regardless if you use VSTO, a COM addin or VBA, you always need this Ribbon.xml. The VSTO ribbon designer is really just a way to make this process easier. From the XML perspective there are two ways to get the combobox filled with items. If the items are static and don't change then you just use `getItemCount/getItemID/getItemLabel` on the `<comboBox>` but if the items are changing during the runtime then you have to use a `<dynamicMenu>` instead of the `<comboBox>` and build a `<menu>` inside of `getContent`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 RibbonDropDownItem item = Factory.CreateRibbonDropDownItem();
```

Comment: This doesn't say how to reference the combobox in the ribbon.

Comment: @Peter
The question is about problem in loading items, not reference.
Anyway, if you want to refer to the control itself, then you'll find it in method declaration
**Office.IRibbonControl control**

Comment: I think haindl's comment on the question is the correct answer to the question. Your answer says how to create items, but not how to add them to the combobox - and I don't think it is possible to add them in an xml ribbon.

Comment: Okay,
haindel comment is also good, you can pick it :)

Answer (score 0):

VISTO has an issue, I too tried adding multiple items from code behind but something went wrong.
But, existing items can be modified dynamically.
Try editing in Ribbon1_Load event.

```
public partial class Ribbon1
{
    private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {
        this.comboBox1.Items[0].Label = "new Lable";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is for ribbon created with the designer, not an xml ribbon.